# How to set an if statement to select keep the rows I need? (or remove the ones I do not need)

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the data frame DT that includes 3 columns: Reg (Regions), Products and values.
What I would like is first to loop over all prodcuts, if for one product I have two elements such as "WLD" and "EUN" within the Reg column, then I will skip this product and go to the next one.

```
COMS <- unique(DT$XX)
for (j in 1:length(COMS)){
CURRENT_COMS <- COMS[j]
df <- filter(DT, XX==CURRENT_COMS) 
if ("WLD" && "EUN" %in% DT$Reg) {next} # Here is the problem
m_OLS_EUN = lm(Y ~ X, data = df)
...}
```

I wrote like this to express if "WLD" and "EUN" both appear for product j then go to next product, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include "WLD" and "EUN" in a vector and test whether each is in the vector `DT$REG`. This will return a logical vector of length 2 indicating whether "WLD" and "EUN" are in `DT$REG` (both `TRUE` if they are both there). Since you want to know if they are both true, you wrap that in  `all()`, which returns `TRUE` only if all elements are `TRUE`:

```r
COMS <- unique(DT$XX)
for (j in 1:length(COMS)){
  CURRENT_COMS <- COMS[j]
  df <- filter(DT, XX==CURRENT_COMS) 
  if (all(c("WLD" && "EUN")) %in% DT$Reg)) {next} # Here is the problem
  m_OLS_EUN = lm(Y ~ X, data = df)
  ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I want to do like if WLD is false and EUN is true then do something, how should I write the code?

Comment: Can you please create a dataset as an example? It's very difficult to help without it.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for the answer again. I tried if (!("WLD" %in% df$Reg) & ("EUN" %in% df$Reg)) and it worked. :)